# net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID when using 'fetch' on local Flask server

Tags: python, reactjs, flask, ssl, cloudflare

I'd like to preface this by saying that this is my first real full-stack application, and I am by no means a knowledgeable webmaster.

### Context

My website, testwebsite.com, has a ReactJS frontend and is running on Ubuntu 20.04 on a Caddy webserver. There is a Python Flask API running on the same server. Flask is running on port 3000 on 0.0.0.0. The website is using Caddy's default self-signed HTTPS. Flask is using a certificate and key created by ZeroSSL. I am using Google Chrome to access my website.

### Problem

The users are able to access the website with HTTPS without any problems. The problem arises from the website's backend Flask API. Every 5 seconds, the React frontend uses `fetch` to query the Flask API at the website's external IP address, which looks like this:

`const response = await fetch("https://123.123.123.123:3000/testing" ...`

However, these calls do not reach the Flask server, and I get the following error in the console:

`GET https://123.123.123.123:3000/testing net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID`

### Attempts to solve

- I have tried using the Caddy certificate and key on the Flask server.
- I have tried running Flask on 127.0.0.1 and replacing the IP address in the Fetch call with 127.0.0.1
- I have tried running the API without SSL and made API calls using http://. This caused a different SSL error.
- I have tried using certificates from the DNS provider, Cloudflare, but this is unsuccessful, as they are not trusted by the browser.
- I have tried running the Flask server in adhoc mode. This yields a different SSL error about the CA authority not being trusted.
- I have tried using Apache as the webserver, but I was using Cloudflare's 'hybrid' DNS and did not try resolving this with Cloudflare certificates. I don't have high hopes.
- I have tried running Flask in CORS to avoid any possible CORS errors. I suspect that this may not be a perfect solution, though, and may be part of the reason that `fetch()` calls to 127.0.0.1:3000 are not making it through to the flask server. I get a "connection refused" error in the console.

### Any suggestions?

I've been stuck on this for weeks. Any and all suggestions are welcome. I would simply like the website to be secured with HTTPS and also be able to call my API. I don't even care if the Flask API has to run on a separate server, without any TLS. I just want it to work. Ideally, I'd be able to call the Flask API without the need for any SSL, but it seems like if I want the website to have SSL, the API must also be secured with SSL.

Answer (score 0):

as I know you need your flask app to run on a domain in order to get a valid https certificate. You can use Certbot after getting a domain and it  will generate you a SSL certificate. Don't forget to add flask-cors to your application for using with fetch API.